# Getting security warning in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I was running Code Analysis of my project in VS 2013 and found below security warning.

**CA5122    P/Invoke declarations should not be safe-critical.  P/Invoke method 'InfoParameters.GetVolumeInformationInvoke(string, StringBuilder, uint, out uint, out uint, out uint, StringBuilder, uint)' is marked safe-critical.  Since P/Invokes may only be called by critical code, this declaration should either be marked as security critical, or have its annotation removed entirely to avoid being misleading.    AmericanEPayWebPunch    PunchInOutBLL.cs    785**

[image]

for below code

```
class InfoParameters
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetVolumeInformation(string Volume, StringBuilder VolumeName, uint VolumeNameSize, out uint SerialNumber, out uint SerialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fs_size);

}
```

So as per the documentation provided by MS on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn621099.aspx , I created a wrapper method for my method but still getting the same issue

```
[assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "GetVolumeInformation")]
    internal static extern bool GetVolumeInformationInvoke(string volume, StringBuilder volumeName, uint volumeNameSize,
        out uint serialNumber, out uint serialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fsSize);
}

class InfoParameters
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static bool GetVolumeInformation(string Volume, StringBuilder VolumeName, uint VolumeNameSize, out uint SerialNumber, out uint SerialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fs_size)
    {
        return SafeNativeMethods.GetVolumeInformationInvoke(Volume, VolumeName, VolumeNameSize, out SerialNumber, out SerialNumberLength, out flags, fs, fs_size);
    }
}
```

I tried the suggestion given by @Lucca by still getting same warning. see below screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn621099.aspx

Comment: already tried the same, I shared the same link in my question

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl - isn't that already linked to from the middle of their question? Is there specific advice on there that you think the OP has missed? If so, it would be worth highlighting the specifics, rather than saying "please read this page that you've said you've already read"

Comment: Is this really an ASP.NET web application? Then you're running into security issues, because your application context may not be allowed to run kernel-functions.

Comment: Yes it's a working/running Asp.Net web application

Answer (score 0):

You need both the `SecuritySafeCritical` and `SecurityCritical` attributes if you're using the `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` attribute to correctly manage the security of any eventual unsafe assembly call. If you don't need the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` remove it and the warning should disappear.

This is the code actually working here (there are still a couple of warning about marshalling, anyway):

```
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [SecurityCritical]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "GetVolumeInformation")]
    internal static extern bool GetVolumeInformationInvoke(string volume, StringBuilder volumeName, uint volumeNameSize,
        out uint serialNumber, out uint serialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fsSize);
}

[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static bool GetVolumeInformation(string Volume, StringBuilder VolumeName, uint VolumeNameSize, out uint SerialNumber, out uint SerialNumberLength, out uint flags, StringBuilder fs, uint fs_size)
{
    return SafeNativeMethods.GetVolumeInformationInvoke(Volume, VolumeName, VolumeNameSize, out SerialNumber, out SerialNumberLength, out flags, fs, fs_size);
}
```

Comment: It was already there, I forgot to write in my question. This doesn't resolve the issue

Comment: both methods are already in the class as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn621099.aspx I modified my question

Comment: Ok, I found out that to unleash this error you need to use [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]; without it you will get no error about security calling. If you need the [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers], than you need both the SecurityAttributes. I updated the answer with that.